# IHM comunication with Api for CQRS+ES

Tags: c#, cqrs, event-sourcing

I started to develp a new project with CQRS/ES. As I understand, one command raised a new event. So, I developped a web api with one action mapped to one command.

List of api action :

```
    [Route("api/user/create"), HttpPost]
    public Task<IActionResult> Handle(Commands.Create command)
    => HandleCommand(command);

    [Route("api/user/update/name"), HttpPost]
    public Task<IActionResult> Handle(Commands.UpdateName command)
    => HandleCommand(command);
```

In my IHM project developped with Blazor, how to communicate with the web api ?
Foreach change in a textbox, i send a http post ?
it's not really a best solution.

I prefer to add a submit button and send one http post. For this solution, how do I communicate all of user's action to web api ?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you to take a look at concepts like DDD. The first thing you have to do is get a clear understanding of your Domain.

Let's say that you're working on a Product Inventory system. In your Blazor app you might well have a "create product" page, containing a form with all the relevant fields (eg. "title", "description", "price" and so on).

The backend would expose a POST endpoint `/products` accepting a `CreateProductDTO` (check what a DTO is if you're unsure). The DTO would then be mapped into an immutable command, which will then get sent to the relative handler.

The idea is not to send *every single user interaction* to the server. You have to make a map of the possible actions exposed by your Domain and work your way up.

Comment: Thanks David Guida. I've read a lot of documents, and finally, I understand that I must use Task-base UI for the front-end. start developping CQRS+ES is really difficult, but It's a big challenge.

Comment: glad it helped. In case you need more info, I have a few articles about ES+CQRS on my blog that might shed some light: https://www.davideguida.com/event-sourcing-in-net-core-part-1-a-gentle-introduction/